# Can email field be used as a lookup field with django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Can an email field in the model be used as a lookup field for the rest api?

I have a model "User" with username=models.CharField() and email=models.EmailField() as members. I would like to set email as the lookup field in the viewset and have the below code for the same.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if 'email' in self.kwargs:
        return User.objects.filter(email=self.kwargs['email'])
    else:
        return User.objects.all()

    lookup_field = 'email'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'email'
```

However, since email field always contains a '.', the lookup fails with "current path didn't match any of these" message. How can we perform a successful api lookup with a value containing a '.' e.g. an email

GET /api/user/abc@def.com

Comment: Show your url config. It is probably defined to accept integer ids for lookup. You should define it to accept an arbitrary string or just email

Answer (score 10):

specify the **`lookup_value_regex`** attribute in the viewset

```
class FooViewset(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    lookup_field = 'email'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'email'
    lookup_value_regex = '[\w@.]+' # here is the new attribute
```

**NOTE:** You don't have to override the **`get_queryset()`** method.

Comment: Thanks. Lookup field was allowing just `[a-z0-9]`, not `@` & `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, I managed as below.

I would lookup with an email field, but impossible it use it in URL endpoints.

As the json from my API contains the good URL endpoints, with their related email, I query the json to get the URL endpoint.
A kind of manual relationship:

```
import requests, json, subprocess

REQUEST_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/?format=json'
login = 'DjangoLogin'
password = 'DjangoPassWord'
response = requests.get(REQUEST_URL, auth=(login, password))

json_data = response.text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
readable_json = json.loads(json_data)

email_reference = YOUR_EMAIL_FIELD
new_firstname = YOUR_FIRSTNAME_FIELD
new_lastname = YOUR_LASTNAME_FIELD

match_count = 0

for results in readable_json['results']:
    match_count += 1
    if results['email'] == email_reference and results['email'] is not None and match_count != 1:
        my_url = results['url']

        my_cmd = 'http -a ' + login + ':' + password + ' PUT ' + my_url + ' firstname="' + new_firstname + '"' + ' lastname="' + new_lastname + '"'

        p = subprocess.Popen(my_cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = p.communicate()
```

More explanation in my website: https://hg-map.fr/astuces/69-django-rest-api

As I searched for a long time, I share this tips into threads that helped me, good luck!